# String to Byte [delphi]

Tags: delphi, byte

I need to store my data into memory. My type data of my data is string. I want to minimize the memory usage. I guess I have to change string into byte. Am I right? If I convert string to byte, that means I have to convert string to TMemoryStream?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean here.  If you have a string variable, it's already stored in memory.  Can you give some more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Before D2009 string type was a byte array as it was ASCII. This was equivalent to byte array with lenght of number of characters + 1 for (hidden in delphi implementation) trailing zero byte. Since D2009 string type is unicode and it takes double the amount of bytes. To convert string you should refer to string type conversions.

Comment: How much data are you planning to store? Working with string data as byte arrays is painful, so you would only use it if you are having problems with the amount of data. And if you are having problems, halving it by using byte arrays instead of strings may not solve the problems anyway.

Comment: @Masson, the string source will be freed. My app read data(=string) from file, then app convert the data into byte.   @too, I'm using D2007.    @Marcelo, about 2000 lines, each lines contain 10 chars.

Comment: @user if you want to read a file into a byte array buffer then do just that and bypass strings altogether

Comment: @user on the other hand, if you want access to it as strings then just use TStringList.LoadFromFile and bask in the simplicity of the TStringList class, its iterator etc.

Comment: You mention in a comment that your string contains **base 64**.  Perhaps you intended to ask how to convert your base-64-encoded string into the corresponding **non-encoded** array of bytes. That would be a meaningful question, and doing that could cut the memory use by about 75 percent.

Comment: @Rob, I can't understand clearly your reply. I use TStringList to load the lines. Decode the string and store a part of it into an array. Freeing the TStringList.

Comment: @user. What Rob is saying is, that Base64 is by a factor 4/3 larger that raw data before encoding. And it is questionable if you really need the encoded data in RAM. If you decode it before reading it then you will gain some memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to convert it then this code will get it done

```
var
  BinarySize: Integer;
  InputString: string;
  StringAsBytes: array of Byte;
begin
  BinarySize := (Length(InputString) + 1) * SizeOf(Char);
  SetLength(StringAsBytes, BinarySize);
  Move(InputString[1], StringAsBytes[0], BinarySize);
```

But as already stated this will not save you memory. The ammount of it used will be practically the same. You will gain nothing from this alone. If you are having to many strings take a different approach. Like something from this list of choices:

1. Use a dictionary and only store each same string once
2. Only hold a portion of all strings in memory. Some sort of cache. Have others on hard drive and use streams to load them
3. If you have very large string consider compressing them.
4. If you are reading from file and you target is binary data, skip the string in the middle. Read the source directly into a byte buffer.

It is hard to give further help without knowing more about the problem.

**EDIT**:

If you really want a minimum memory footprint and you can live with a little lower speed (but still very fast) you can use [Suffix Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) or [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) or event a simple [Binary Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). They can work directly from hard drive and can be very fast for searching. If you then cache a subset of the data to RAM, you get the optimal solution memory vs. speed wise.

Anyway given the ammount of data you claim to have it seems no memory optimization is needed at all. 22MB of RAM is hardly an issue and not worth optimizing.

Comment: So there will be no different about memory consumption, if I store my data as string or byte array..  Does it same if I use `AStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  with AStream do WriteBuffer(AText[1],Length(AText));` ?      Actually I am doing your second choice.

Comment: Yes it will be the same if you use string or byte array or even TMemoryStream. Actually with TMemoryStream you will even use more memory becouse of an extra object. As I said look for memory optimization elsewhere. I pointed out a few options. I you want more precise answer you have to describe you problem in more details.

Comment: My problem right now is simple. I want to store my data into memory and I want to optimize the memory usage. That's all. My real problem is why I store my data into memory? Actually my data is array of string. Every string in array is a portion of string from each line of the file. This is my implementation to compare a string input with my data. First compare the portion of input with data in memory, if match then with index of array, recheck the input with reading the data/line in file based on index of array.

Comment: @user Load your lines into a TStringList, and save the Index into the Objects property. Next sort the list. When you want to compare input do it with binary search. Since you have 10600 strings you only need log_2 10600 comparisons, i.e. not very many. You are asking the wrong question, and you have accepted an answer that does not solve your real problem, no offence to @Runner who has answered in good faith. Memory is not your problem, poor choice of algorithm is.

Comment: I don't say my algorithm is good. The question is memory optimization about storing string, not about my algorithm . too has explain that. I do use sorting and binary search. My data is growing up. I think with convert string to byte, I will save the memory. But in D2007, it won't. Sorry for poor English.

Comment: @David Heffernan. None taken :) I have answered as best as I could given the data I had available.

Comment: I still do not know what the exact nature of the problem is (the whole concept), but given that you seem to be using Base64 encoding you could compress the data in memory, but only if the single Base64 string is long enough to make some gain. Otherwise if your strings are 2000 chars long it still takes only about 22MB of memory (if you have 10600 of them). Firefox takes about 200MB when running. 22MB is very little. If you want to save memory my above points are still valid. But without knowing more this is the best I can do.

Comment: Hmm.. I have a string "aa|bb", I encode it with Base64 , store it in a line/file. TStringList load the line, decrypt it, "aa" stored into array. App compare input with "aa"/array, if match then app do some process to get "bb" (= an return value from some  function). Now app read the line from file based on index of array, decrypt the line and compare the return value with "bb". That's it my algorithm

Comment: Thanks for your edited reply. It gives me more information. I think my question has been solved by @too and @Runner. About my algorithm (above this reply), yes it's poor but that is the best I can do for my app (or for me?). @Runner, 22 MB is just for one module :) , no need to respond, you have provided many information.

Comment: @user I don't think you fully understand what you are doing. Converting to base64 uses more memory than leaving it as a Delphi string! Why do you ask a question and then not listen to the replies?

Comment: @David, I encrypt my string then encode it with base64. The purpose is to make my data unreadable. 3 am here, sleep :)

Comment: @user I can't imagine anybody would be able to detect a base64 encoding!!

Comment: @user How does this answer save memory, even laying aside the base64 question? Isn't array of byte essentially the same as string in D2007? Where does the memory saving (which you don't need) come from?

Comment: I think reverser can detect it. David, no, I don't change my code at all. The answer does not save memory, but @Runner tell me I can't save the memory because length of string and length of byte are same in D2007 (if I don't wrong to understand the reply)

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain this is an optimization that is needed?

2000 lines that are 10 characters long is only 20000 characters.

In most environments, that's tiny. Most machines have considerably more RAM than that.  Most disks are considerably larger than that.  And, usually, sending and receiving that much information is trivial over the web.

Perhaps your situation is unique. Maybe you have large number of 20000 character data sets, or very slow web access over which to transmit this date, etc.  But, I'd encourage you to consider whether you aren't perhaps trying to optimize something that even if you are very successful in implementing, won't significantly change your application's performance in the real world.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Actually it is now 10600 lines, each line contain base64. So I think I need this optimization .

Comment: @user I doubt you do need the optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

Make your storage type tutf8string. It can be simply assigned from tunicodestring, and conversion should be safe.